# NEXTJS: Executing script while navigating not only on window.load

Tags: reactjs, next.js

can you help me with the following?

I'm generating static sites from WordPress content, and some post has a script in its content:

```
const fetchApiResponse =  '<p>post content</p><script>console.log('Activated')</script>';
```

I'm inyecting this html on nextjs using dangerouslySetInnerHTML:

```
<div
  className="wordpress-content"
  id="wordpress-content"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: fetchApiResponse }}
/>
```

**This console log is triggered when loading the first page, but not when using the next navigation**. If I navigate to another page and then go to the same page this console.log is not triggered.

It is as if the  tags of the content are not read when navigating, but yes on the first load or when event "window.onload" happen.

Any of you guys has faced faced with that? how can i solve it? The idea is trigger the console.log() on every navigation not only page load.

Thanks in advance!

I tried to use html-parse and detect if script exist, and simulate executing but so low performance.

I guess a kind of observable or something could help but not sure if exists a solution a bit friendly.